# Youtube upload failing with 403 - Download Service Forbidden

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, gdata-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using the `google-api-nodejs-client` and I'm trying to script up an uploader. I've finally got to the stage where everything is OAuth2 authenticated and I can make requests.

When trying to do an upload however, I'm getting 403 - Download Service Forbidden errors. Googling the error is returning utterly nothing (a rarity these days), and the official error code listing doesn't list it.

I've attached the JSON response below.

```
 { errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'downloadServiceForbidden',
       message: 'Download Service Forbidden' },
     [length]: 1 ],
  code: 403,
  message: 'Download Service Forbidden' }
```

Has anyone seen this or knows what it means?

My upload code.

```
var yt_api = googleapis.discover('youtube', 'v3');

var auth_scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"
]

var authClient = new googleapis.OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);


//performs the authorisation with the above scopes
ensureAuthorisation(authClient, doRequest);


function doRequest() {

    log.msg('Executing...');
    yt_api.execute(function(err, client){

        // open the video as a stream
        var buffer = fs.readFileSync('../files/test.mp4');

        client
            .youtube.videos.insert({part: "contentDetails", mine: true})
            .withAuthClient(authClient)
            .withMedia('video/*', buffer)
            .execute(function(err, response){

                if (err) {
                    log.err("Error in upload");
                    dumpObj(err);
                } else {
                    log.msg("Succeeded!");
                }

            });

    });

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what you're doing? `403` in HTTP is just `Forbidden`.

Comment: I assumed that if there was an authentication issue it would a more general error, the downloadServiceForbidden reason seems undocumented. I shall update the question with the upload code.